# Typesetting part of a publication list

Tags: bibliographies, context

I found out that I can use `\doplacepublicationindeed{Someone2016}` to typeset a single publication ahead of time.

I can’t figure out how to influence the way numbers are typeset:

```
\def\publistnumber#1{\expandafter\message{>>>#1}#1\hfill~}
\setuppublicationlist[numbercommand=\publistnumber]
\doplacepublicationindeed{Someone2016}
```

will result in

```
tex error       > tex error on line 24 in file parts/c_publist.ctx: ! 
Missing number, treated as zero

<to be read again> 
\edef 
\currentlistsymbol ->\edef 
                           \p_symbol {\listparameter \c!symbol }\doifelseins...
\romannumerals #1->\clf_romannumerals \numexpr #1
                                                 \relax 
\publistnumber #1->\romannumerals {#1}
                                      \hfill ~
\spac_align_simple_left #1->{#1
                               \hss }
\25>:135>:abc ...umbercommand \currentlistsymbol }
                                                  \else \setbox \b_strc_list...
...
```

If I define this instead:

```
\def\publistnumber#1{\expandafter\message{>>>#1}#1\hfill~}
```

… the log will contain `>>>\currentlistsymbol`.

Comment: try `\setuppublicationlist[numbercommand={\publistnumber}]`. I remember having troubles with macro keys that weren't in braces. Don't garanty it works in your case.

Comment: Would you mind adding a fully compiliable MWE?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do.  The command `\doplacepublicationindeed` is from the `oldbibtex` module.  You should be using the integrated publications module nowadays.